# R: stringr to find the start location for rows

Tags: r, apply, stringr

I can use stringr to find the start "http" location at first row,

```
library(stringr)

a <- str_locate(message[1,], "http")[1]
a 
[1] 38
```

I want to find the start location for each row, and use "apply" fuction:

```
message$location <- apply(message, 1, function(x) str_locate(message[x,], "http")[1])
```

But it shows all "NA" values, could I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As we are using anonymous function call (`function(x)`), we can use the input variable for each row as `x` i.e. `str_locate(x, ...)`

```
apply(message, 1, function(x) str_locate(x, "http")[1])
#[1] 11 16
```

Or without specifying the anonymous function

```
apply(message, 1, str_locate, pattern="http")[1,]
#[1] 11 16
```

As @thelatemail mentioned, if we are only looking for patterns in the first column, we don't need an `apply` loop.

```
str_locate(message[,1], "http")[,1]
#[1] 11 16
```

#### data

```
message <- data.frame(V1= c("Something http://www...", 
            "Something else http://www.."), v2= 1:2)
```

Comment: Surely the `apply` isn't needed at all?

Comment: @thelatemail Based on the code, I assume it is not needed.  Thanks for the comment.